# Hazelcast mancenter partition groups monitoring

Tags: hazelcast

How can I monitor partition groups using Hazelcast Management Center to validate my configuration.
Is there a way to understand how my custom partition grouping works?
Hazelcast mancenter seems missing that feature and it is also not possible to see it in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to see the partition group config of a member in the Member details page under the "Member Configuration" box. There you can see the effective configuration of a member, including the partition group config.

I'm not sure what you mean by `how my custom partition grouping works`. If there's a feature you want to be included, you can [create an issue in the Hazelcast GitHub repository](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new). Please make sure to explain what you want in more precise terms if you decide to do so.